# Could not identify intended function with name

Tags: python, ethereum, cryptocurrency, web3py

Could not identify the intended function with name `swapTokensForExactTokens`, positional argument(s) of type `(<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'list'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'int'>)` and keyword argument(s) of type `{}`.
Found 1 function(s) with the name `swapTokensForExactTokens`: ['swapTokensForExactTokens(uint256,uint256,address[],address,uint256)']
Function invocation failed due to no matching argument types.

I am getting this error, while it seems all my variable types are correct

I am using the following code:

```
ChecksumA = w3.toChecksumAddress("0x15F517ccAa1420A0bf882052A41A81a152D1A285")
ChecksumB = w3.toChecksumAddress("0x72C262985366cf25Cc81629d01393CE3213C4F79")

tx = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(
            Router.functions.swapTokensForExactTokens(1, 1,
                                                      [ChecksumA, ChecksumB], w3.toChecksumAddress(acct.address),
                                                      (int(time.time()) + 100000)).buildTransaction(
                {'from': acct.address, "nonce": nonce, "gas": 200000, 'gasPrice': gasprice}), priv)
        txsigned = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(tx.rawTransaction)
        tx_receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(txsigned)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the code and/or documentation for swapTokensForExactTokens?